# How to adjust MsMpEng.exe (Windows Defender) scanning schedule when Task Scheduler has no effect?

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-tasks, windows-defender

Every day around 11 PM my CPU use goes to 100% and I hear fans spinning up. Task Manager shows it's C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Platform\4.18.2207.7-0\MsMpEng.exe. Resource Monitor shows that MsMpEng is scanning my disk intensively.

I have thousands of small files in multiple folders, so the scan takes at least half an hour (CPU is at 100% the whole time) and sometimes it can make my PC stutter.

In general, I'm pretty cautious about what I open and I find this everyday scanning to be overkill. So I looked for solutions online and I adjusted the scheduled task to run once a week.

[image: Windows Defender scheduled task]

But it did not help at all! I even tried to disable the scan scheduled task altogether - no change, MsMpEng.exe keeps starting up every day around 11 PM.

What else could be triggering MsMpEng.exe every day and how do I take full control over it?

Comment: You cannot actually turn WD off except for a short time. Also it does real time scanning.  Consolidate the files (above) into a small number of folders and then whitelist the folders. WD will not scan these.

Answer (score 0):

*Possibly*, a work-around: set the priority to low with a batch script. Create a file, e.g. *ReducePriorityDfndr.bat*, containing

`wmic process where name="MsMpEng.exe" CALL setpriority 64`

Put a shortcut to it in the *Startup* folder, and set the shortcut to run as Administrator.

You might also schedule the task to run *daily* at 23:00. Perhaps a week was too long. Also, when setting the task, try running as Admin.

Comment: MsMpEng.exe seems to be protected against attempts to change its affinity / priority. At least when I try online suggestions to adjust them in Task Manager, running as admin, I get access denied exception for all attempts to adjust MsMpEng.exe settings. Maybe Defender service has some kind of a built in timer that works on its own without the task scheduler.