Windows Defender constantly writing to my harddisk for days now
I have this computer for quite some years now and I pretty much know its behavior. I never wrote to the disk in idle for such a long time. Recently I rebooted with an windows update and since then the Disk LED is lighting nonstop. Investigating what might access the disk I disabled indexer but that didn't help. Now I have MsMpEng.exe hanging there and constantly writing to the disk.

So I tried to stop real time protection, set a schedule for scan at monday afternoon, and set the conditions for the task to when the computer is idle for 30min. I restarted but the disk is still constantly accessed. It is an SSD and I really don't like having it constantly being written to. And why is it even writing when it's, if at all, supposed to scan?

MsMpEng.exe does do an incredible amount of reading and writing, particularly after updates, as it performs a full scan. Wait for it to finish, which might take a day or two more. You can lower it's priority with https://superuser.com/questions/1742215/how-to-adjust-msmpeng-exe-windows-defender-scanning-schedule-when-task-schedul. Beware of some  Windows updates, which might damage the drive: https://www.techradar.com/news/windows-10-update-could-be-damaging-your-ssd, https://www.tomsguide.com/news/windows-10-update-could-kill-your-ssd-what-you-need-to-know

Would be the first time in years, that Defender needs days for scanning after an update.
